# Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain still exists, even after "gradle wrapper"

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Basically the title, i build a flutter project, try to run it and it always fails. Downloaded java, gradle, run gradle wrapper and it told me to run gradle init or else it falied. Still, nothing worked! What should i do?

Comment: Please share more error logs that you are facing while running app

Comment: @Hardik Mehta i just get the "could not find or load main class..." nothing else, then it exits. Cant even run any app, and i have not even made anything, just created a test application to see if it would work

Comment: you can try solution from this link : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14422